# call jsp from javascript with parameter

Tags: javascript, jsp, redirect

i have created a button on its onclick() event i call a method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
validate()
{
.....
window.location='reg.jsp';
}
</script>
```

it doesn't take any value of the textbox to the reg.jsp page

If i use `<form action="reg.jsp" method="POST">` it takes the value of textbox to the next page but i can't do the things which are to be executed in `validate()` method

provide a solution which may help to redirect to next page with value of textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<form action="reg.jsp" method="POST">` and call `validate()` function `onsubmit` of your form.Return true if form is valid else return false.Returning false from `validate()` will prevent your form from being submitted.

```
<form action="reg.jsp" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
    ...
    ...        
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah..I edited that.Posted that without reviewing...Thanks for verifying:)

Comment: for this i must have return type in validate()

Comment: @Ajay  Yes your `validate()` must return false in case you don't want page to be redirected, true otherwise